# Four teenagers racing spaceships and fighting evil undercover

Tags: story-identification

I've been looking around for a show I used to watch as a kid and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I remember it was an anime style cartoon about 4 teenagers who raced small flyers, kinda like the pod races in Star Wars. And then they would transform -guns popping out and stuff- and they would fight the bad guys while being undercover.

I think I remember the four teenagers being a girl and three guys.

Also there was floating cities.

Anyone know the name? Let me know if you need further details

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Please consider taking the [about]. You say you watched it when you were a kid, but we don't know your age, so we don't know when that was. Maybe you can give some more context ? Please format your text better in the future. I'll take time to edit this one.

Comment: Sounds a little like Oban Star Racers